# Make a class with name Category in a activity and I want to call the object of this class in the main activity on Android

Tags: java, android

Make a class with name `Catagory` in an activity, and I want to call the object of this class in the `mainactivity` on Android.

```
 package com.example.listviewexample;

    public class Catagory {

        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Catagory(int id, String name, String desc, String type) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.type = type;
        }

        private String desc;
        private String type;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem you facing ?

Comment: where is you mainactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare this class on a different separate Java class. First declare these variable in your Catagory class:

```
public class Catagory {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String type;

    //Your rest of the code
}
```

Then simply in your MainActivity.java, declare its object:

```
ArrayList<Catagory> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Catagory(1, "Name 1", "Description 1", "Type 1")); // Its index is 0.
list.add(new Catagory(2, "Name 2", "Description 2", "Type 2")); // Its index is 1.
list.add(new Catagory(3, "Name 3", "Description 3", "Type 3")); // Its index is 2.
list.add(new Catagory(4, "Name 4", "Description 4", "Type 4")); // Its index is 3.

//Keep on adding these as many as you want, and another way:
Catagory person = new Catagory(5, "Lisa", "Female", "Good");
list.add(person); // Its index will be 4.

//To access these variables just use index:
String firstName=list.get(0).getName(); // Will return Name1.
String secondDescription=list.get(1).getDesc); // Will return Description 2.

//To change the some values, just use this:
list.get(0).setName("Alex");
list.get(0).setDesc("Male");
list.get(0).setId(9);
```

Comment: ArrayListCatagory> c= newArrayList<catagory>();

Comment: Catagory class is the seperate class in catagory.java file and mainactivty.java is the seperate file i want to display all parameter in mainactivity.java by calling object of catagory class using Array list .

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the class separately. And then call its constructor by making a object of its class.

**Making the class separately**

```
public class Catagory implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String type;

    public Catagory(int id, String name, String desc, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
 }
```

**Then you can call it in an activity as:**

```
Catagory objCatagory = new Catagory(id, name, desc, type); //This will call the constructor and create a object with initial values you have passed as parameter
```